# IndexOutOfBoundsException with index < size with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, mapreduce

### Problem

Using threads and get an `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 0` error from some threads while other threads execute fine. When debugging the exception the problem seems to be `get(index int)` in Arraylist class.

```
public E get(int index) {
        Objects.checkIndex(index, size);
        return elementData(index);
    }
```

The `Objects.checkIndex(index, size)` is passed the correct values( in this case size is 9 and index 1) but in the Objects class the size parameter is 0.

#### Code

Program is using an attempt at implementing MapReduce and here is the code for the start of the reduce threading

```
Thread t = new Thread(() ->  {

            for(int i=0; i<words.size();i++ ){
              reduce(words.get(i), lists.get(i), reduceCallback);
            }
          });
```

reduce function and reduce callback were given to us by professor and work in single thread

reduce function

```
public static void reduce(String word, List<String> list, ReduceCallback<String, String, Integer> callback) {

    Map<String, Integer> reducedList = new HashMap<>();
    for(String file: list) {
      reducedList.merge(file, 1, Integer::sum);
    }
    callback.reduceDone(word, reducedList);
  }
```

and reduceCallback

```
final ReduceCallback<String, String, Integer> reduceCallback = new ReduceCallback<>() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void reduceDone(String k, Map<String, Integer> v) {
          output.put(k, v);
        }
      };
```

Comment: You're not passing `size` into `get(int index)` so where is that value coming from?

Comment: `public E get(int index)` is in java.util.ArrayList so size is just the `private int size` in that class

Comment: `The Objects.checkIndex(index, size) is passed the correct values( in this case size is 9 and index 1) but in the Objects class the size parameter is 0. `         This is impossible and probably a problem of debugging in multithread environment. Can it happen that `words` and `lists` sizes are different?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. You must be either modifying `lists` or making an incorrect assumption about how many there actually are in that array. How many "lists of string lists" are you iterating through? Yeah, if the number of `words` and `lists` are different this could happen.

Comment: @SergeyVasnev i dont think so they are created and modified at same time

Comment: @macrofox modifying lists seems to have been the problem. 
Immediately after thread was created I cleared lists, this is probably the reason size==0 in Objects as well. 
I created a local threadLists variable which seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks